# Decorator pattern with structuremap 2.6

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I am using StructureMap 2.6 and trying to use the decorator pattern:

```
        For<IBusRefTranslator>().Use<BusRefTranslator>()
            .EnrichWith((x) => new LoggingBusRefTranslator(x))
            .Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(connectionString);
```

This works perfectly, however my LoggingBusRefTranslator has a dependency that needs to be resolved, so I want StructureMap to build it.  I just can't figure out the right route and most of the examples for enrichment that I can find use the old syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by moving all my dependencies for my decorator to constructor dependencies and using an alternative form of the EnrichWith extension:

```
        For<IBusRefTranslator>().Use<BusRefTranslator>()
            .EnrichWith<IBusRefTranslator>((c, x) => new LoggingBusRefTranslatorDecorator(x, c.GetInstance<IFusionLogService>()))
            .Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(connectionString);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this myself by writing the following extension method. The advantage is that the syntax of the configuration is simpler and that the dependencies of the decorator are automatically injected rather than having to deal with them yourself in a `new` statement. The syntax for decorating an object would be as follows:

```
For<IBusRefTranslator>().Use<BusRefTranslator>()
    .Decorate().With<LoggingBusRefTranslatorDecorator>(); // dependencies and decoratee automatically injected
```

Extension class:

```
public static class StructureMapExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the defined instance to be wrapped by an instance of another decorator type
    /// </summary>
    public static DecorateConfig<T> Decorate<T>(this SmartInstance<T> instance)
    {
        return new DecorateConfig<T>(instance);
    }

    public class DecorateConfig<T>
    {
        private readonly SmartInstance<T> _instance;
        internal DecorateConfig(SmartInstance<T> instance)
        {
            _instance = instance;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypeAndAllBaseTypes(Type t)
        {
            if (t == typeof(object))
                yield break;

            yield return t;

            foreach (var @base in t.GetInterfaces().Union(GetTypeAndAllBaseTypes(t.BaseType)))
                yield return @base;
        }

        private static string FindArgumentNameForWrappedInner(Type decoratorType)
        {
            foreach (var t in GetTypeAndAllBaseTypes(typeof(T)))
            {
                var argumentName = new Plugin(decoratorType).FindArgumentNameForType(t, CannotFindProperty.Ignore);
                if (argumentName != null)
                    return argumentName;
            }

            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Type " + decoratorType + " has no constructor arguments of type " + typeof(T));
        }

        public SmartInstance<TDecorator> With<TDecorator>()
        {
            var decoratorInstance = new SmartInstance<TDecorator>();
            _instance.EnrichWith((context, inner) => decoratorInstance
                .WithCtorArg(FindArgumentNameForWrappedInner(typeof(TDecorator))).EqualTo(inner)
                .Build(typeof (TDecorator), (BuildSession) context));

            return decoratorInstance;
        }
    }
```